# Passing Nodes to template literal & rendering it?

Tags: javascript, template-literals, nodelist

I have a function returning a template literal:

```
function generateStuff(nodes) {
 const output = `<ul>${nodes}</ul>`;

 return document.body.innerHTML = output;
}
```

`nodes` is an array of `<li>` elements made with `createElement` and then added to `nodes` via `appendChild`.

Is there a way of render a list with `generateStuff(nodes)`? Right now all it returns is `<ul>[object NodeList]</ul>` and I just want it to return proper HTML with working links etc.

I suppose I need to parse it somehow but as this is JS and NodeList is native to it maybe there's a method in place for it already?

Comment: To be clear, your function returns a *string*. It uses a template literal to *create* that string, but since the template literal isn't tagged, evaluating it always results in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of render a list with generateStuff(nodes)?

Yes, but I'd consider changing how you're doing this instead. But the way you'd do it is with a round-trip through HTML:

```
function generateStuff(nodes) {
    const output = `<ul>${Array.from(nodes, (node) => node.outerHTML)}</ul>`;

    return (document.body.innerHTML = output);
}
```

But that's inefficient and lossy (loses event handlers on the nodes, for instance). Instead of using a template literal, consider appending the nodes directly:

```
function generateStuff(nodes) {
    const ul = document.createElement("ul");
    for (const node of nodes) {
        ul.appendChild(node);
    }
    // Or replace the loop with: `ul.append(...nodes)`

    document.body.innerHTML = "";
    document.body.appendChild(ul);
    return ul.outerHTML; // **If** you really need to return HTML, but hopefully not
}
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> I think I might have overly simplified my case, normally I wouldn't have use template literal here but instead of  I have like 20 nested containers there. Your second approach seems really cool but what if ul is inside of a x different containers? How do I append to  then? Do I still have to manually create and append every single one of them? That's what I'm trying to avoid here.

You could create the structure by assigning to `innerHTML` with a means of identifying the `ul`, then once the structure exists, do the append:

```
function generateStuff(nodes) {
    // Create a new replacement `body` element
    const body = document.createElement("body");
    // Create the structure
    body.innerHTML = "<ul class='target'></ul>";
    // Get the `ul` and append to it
    const ul = body.querySelector(".target");
    ul.append(...nodes);

    // Replace the element
    document.body.replaceWith(body);

    // **If** you really need to return HTML
    return document.body.innerHTML;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const nodes = Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => {
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = "li #" + i;
        return li;
    });
    generateStuff(nodes);
});

function generateStuff(nodes) {
    // Create a new replacement `body` element
    const body = document.createElement("body");
    // Create the structure
    body.innerHTML = "<ul class='target'></ul>";
    // Get the `ul` and append to it
    const ul = body.querySelector(".target");
    ul.append(...nodes);

    // Replace the element
    document.body.replaceWith(body);

    // **If** you really need to return HTML
    return document.body.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Go!">
```

Comment: I think I might have overly simplified my case, normally I wouldn't have use template literal here but instead of `<ul>` I have like 20 nested containers there. Your second approach seems really cool but what if `ul` is inside of a x different containers? How do I append to `<ul>` then? Do I still have to manually create and append every single one of them? That's what I'm trying to avoid here. Thank you!

Comment: @Wordpressor - I've added to the end of the question to address that situation.

Comment: Thanks, that's so great. So basically I had to replace template literal with just `"`. One extra question though - why recreating and replacing `body`? Is it an anti-pattern to use `the default body`?

Comment: @Wordpressor - No, it's just it saves us a step since you were fully replacing its content (`document.body.innerHTML = ___`). If you want, you can reuse it by doing `document.body.innerHTML = ""; document.body.append(...body.childNodes);` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `document.createElement` and `Element#append`.

```js
function generateStuff(nodes) {
  const el = document.createElement('ul');
  el.append(...nodes);
  document.body.append(el);
  return el.outerHTML;
}
console.log(generateStuff([...Array(3)].map((_, i) => Object.assign(document.createElement('li'), {textContent: i}))));
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I forget that `append` accepts multiple nodes...